# creating primary keys with constraints or not in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints, primary-key

In mysql, say I have:

```
create table users(
id not null
)
```

Let's say I need to make id as a primary key. What is the difference between:

```
create table users(
id primary key not null
)
```

and

```
create table users(
id not null
primary key (id))
```

and

```
create table users(
id not null
constraint pk primary key (id))
```

I've been searching a lot for the meaning of constraints in this context, but I only find how to use them, not what it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key is both `not null` and `unique`.  So, this is very, very similar to a primary key:

```
create table users (
    id int not null unique
)
```

The one additional feature of a primary key is that it is usually also the clustered index for the table.

A primary key declaration *is* a constraint.  It has the following properties:

- The columns are `not null`.
- The columns are unique.
- Only one primary key declaration is allowed per table (although multiple columns can be in the primary key).

In addition, the primary key columns often form a clustered index.

Except for the third condition, it is possible to declare these using multiple constraint declarations.

Comment: So what is "constraint" use for? Sorry I don't know much about sql statements. But it seems I can use the primary key without having to use the "constraint name primary key (column)" syntax

Comment: A constraint can be a foreign key, check, primary key, unique, or not null constraint.  These are used so the database can enforce such declared properties on the data.  (Note that MySQL does not enforce check constraints.)

Comment: does this mean, "constraint name primary key(column)" is just syntactic sugar for column primary key not null?

Comment: @morbidCode . . . Almost, but not quite.  "Primay key" is almost syntactic sugar for "unique not null".  However, you can have multiple "unique not null" columns in the table, but only one "primary key".